# why does Ruby throw warnings for private attributes

Tags: ruby, private, language-design

Take the example class:

```
# in ./example.rb
class Example
  private
    attr_accessor :name
end
```

When I run it in verbose mode, Ruby throws warnings at me:

```
$ ruby -W2 ./example.rb
example.rb:3: warning: private attribute?
```

Why is this not recommended?

Comment: I don't know why the Ruby team discommends private `attr_accessor` methods, but I think they're preferable to using instance variables because subsequent changes are easier. Sandi Metz also thinks this: http://rubyrogues.com/087-rr-book-clubpractical-object-oriented-design-in-ruby-with-sandi-metz/

Comment: The warning has been removed in Ruby 2.3, see https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10967

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it doesn't make much sense to define a getter/setter that is not visible from the outside in most cases. We generally use `attr_accessor` only to expose an instance variable outside of the class. However, the `private` keyword defeats this purpose by making the generated getter/setter methods invisible to the outside world.

The only reason you would want to use a private setter/getter is when there is some additional logic involved. In this case, however, you would have to define those methods manually with `def`, anyway.

Comment: I use private getter/setters frequently. I'd rather use `foo` than `@foo` because, if I find I need a default or something, I can `def foo` and not have to change all the references. Same for the setter.

Comment: That is what I meant by the last paragraph: In this case, you will have to `def foo`, because you have additional logic.

Comment: sorry, I wasn't clear. I meant that if you use `@foo` and find you need additional logic, you have to change `@foo` everywhere. Whereas if you do `private; attr_accessor :foo` and use `foo`, if you find you need additional logic, you just need to `def foo`, not search-and-replace `@foo`.

Comment: @p11y at times I want to expose an instance variable via a getter, but I want the setter to be private. I prefer not to use `@var` and an accessor instead because doing so changes instance variables from data, splattered all over the place, to behaviour, isolated in one place.

Comment: Its a good tenet in OOP to always use your methods, even for internal use. In the case of this name attribute, say in the future it becomes something more complicated than an attribute.  If you have used @name, then you'll need to replace those with calls to the name method.

As such, I'm surprised that Ruby throws this warning.  It seems contrary to good OOP advice, IMO.

Comment: Bill, thanks for your comment. The problem is that there is no clear rule whether or not to use accessors for exclusively internal access. You might as well end up with a horde of accessors that could be easily replaced with ivar access. Feels wrong for me, too.

Comment: Agree, that it is a basics of OOP - encapsulation. I always use private or protected (for comparisons) `attr_reader`s for my data - following the rule of the thumb: If you want to peek into object's data, then you better off putting this behavior inside of object that has this data. That way, if internal representation of data changes, I don't need to fix hundreds of files and tests suites. Or you move the data into different object with all related behavior if object starts having too much responsibility (~> one).

Answer (score 1):

Although I've accepted [@padde](https://stackoverflow.com/users/192702/padde)'s answer, I would like to share some code for future reference.

I wanted to check [@Babai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2462559/babai)'s answer about the default access levels of the attribute methods.

So here's how it works. I'll demonstrate on the source from `2.0.0-p247`.

This is the source of `attr_accessor`:

```
static VALUE
rb_mod_attr_accessor(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE klass)
{
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<argc; i++) {
rb_attr(klass, rb_to_id(argv[i]), TRUE, TRUE, TRUE);
    }
    return Qnil;
}
```

As you can see, it's calling the `rb_attr` function for each argument. (I'm guessing `argc` stands for `argument counter`.) So we have to look at the `rb_attr` source to understand how this all works:

```
void
rb_attr(VALUE klass, ID id, int read, int write, int ex)
{
    const char *name;
    ID attriv;
    VALUE aname;
    rb_method_flag_t noex;

    if (!ex) {
      noex = NOEX_PUBLIC;
    }
    else {


      if (SCOPE_TEST(NOEX_PRIVATE)) {
        noex = NOEX_PRIVATE;
        rb_warning((SCOPE_CHECK(NOEX_MODFUNC)) ?
          "attribute accessor as module_function" :
          "private attribute?");
      }
      else if (SCOPE_TEST(NOEX_PROTECTED)) {
        noex = NOEX_PROTECTED;
      }
      else {
        noex = NOEX_PUBLIC;
      }
    }

    /* more logic that's not relevant for this explanation */
}
```

As you can see, the interpreter checks if the access level is `NOEX_PRIVATE` and raises errors if it is.

Comment: Good One..! friend..I like your efforts.. :)